# In EmberJs is it possible to get Class object from an instance of the same Class?

Tags: ember.js

Suppose you have

```
var A = Ember.Object.extend({});
A.reopenClass({
   myVariable: 'hello'
});

var a = A.create();
```

Is there a way from `a` to get the `A` object in order to get the `myVariable` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a.constructor`

`a.constructor === A`

`a.constructor.myVariable === A.myVariable`